# Rental contract specifies I have to pay the UK television license even if I don't own transmission equipment

Tags: united-kingdom, rent

My rental contract which I'm about to sign states the following clause.

> "Further Charges to be paid by the Tenant: (...)"  To pay the
> television licence regardless of the ownership of the transmission
> equipment;"

Is this clause enforceable? If not should I sign first and then mention that I will not be owning any broadcasting equipment and will not be paying the license fee or do I need to tell them in advance and ask them to strike the clause (they say the contract is non-negotiable).

If I sign the contract as is, do I really have to pay the fee even though I am not required by the licensing authority?

Comment: This is probably just trying to clarify that the _landlord_ will _not_ pay for a TV license, even if they are providing physical TV equipment as part of the rental.

Comment: alexg is probably right, but that's a horrendously-written clause! "Regardless of who owns any receiving equipment" would be better (a TV licence does not license *transmission*!)

Comment: Perhaps meant to cover BBC vs Sky vs whomever - the landlord is not responsible for whatever TV choices the renter makes.

Comment: Of course not – it means the tenant is responsible whoever owns the equipment (say rented equipment). But note that it's not just about owning a television. If you watch live on any channel, TV service or streaming service, or use BBC iPlayer, you need to be covered by a TV Licence. This applies to any device you use, including a TV, computer, laptop, phone, tablet, games console or digital box. Unless you are living in a vacuum it would be very unusual not to need a TV licence.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It makes sense to me. Transmission equipment would be the hardware to transmit the signal to your receiver. The landlord does not intend to provide receiver equipment, i.e. your TV, but the landlord might provide a community antenna and distribution system.

Comment: @user71659 The community antenna is still receiving equipment, not transmission equipment. It might conceivably be called a distribution system, but that's not transmission either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UK's [TV Licensing](https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/check-if-you-need-one/business-and-organisations/residential-landlords-aud15) states

> As a landlord, the TV Licence is your responsibility if you installed the device, unless the tenancy agreement specifies that it’s the tenants’ responsibility.

So the clause is an overall disclaimer of responsibility. It isn't a requirement to hold a TV license if you have no means of watching live TV or streaming services.